# How to build the library file into the DEB package and not into my system, using qmake?

Tags: linux, qt, build, debian, deb

I am trying to build my first library.

Libraries ought to be installed in different architectures. A library built for i386 usually goes at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ but if built for amd64 it goes to /usr/lib/amd64-linux-gnu/

So, my debian/rules file

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- LIB_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
```

I am able to take the LIB_INSTALL_DIR inside my .pro file:

```
isEmpty(LIB_INSTALL_DIR){
    message("LIB_INSTALL_DIR is empty. It shouldn't be if this isn't an example build.")
    DESTDIR = .
} else {
    DESTDIR = $$LIB_INSTALL_DIR
}

message(Library will be placed at $$DESTDIR)
```

The thing is that DESTDIR tries to send the library in my own filesystem and not to build it into the deb package. For example, it tries to send it on my own /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/, but it is unable, because it doesn't have the permission to do so.

On the other hand,

```
target.files = *.so
target.path = $$LIB_INSTALL_DIR
INSTALLS+=target
```

fails as well. Inside the .deb package I can find the created /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ folder, but it is empty, simply because the INSTALLS runs the installations that it has to do prior to build time, not after it.

Finally, I cannot pass any variable inside debian/install, something that would be very convenient.

I know that this is could also be a Qt question, but I think that this is the right place to ask it because I may be suggested to use some other method for handling this.

Answer (score 0):

`DESTDIR` has a special meaning for install targets: it is used to prefix the actual install targets with an alternative root-directory.
the usual build-systems in Debian make use of this feature by setting `DESTDIR` to `/path/where/the/package/is/built/debian/tmp` or similar - so this means that a properly working `DESTDIR` is *crucial* to install the files into the package rather than your system.

you might want to have a look how this is handled by other packages that use `dh`, `CMake` and install into `/usr/lib/<arch>`.

a quick search revealed that the *libssh2* is such a package, and it uses the following in `debian/rules`:

```
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH ?= $(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS += --libdir=\$${prefix}/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)

%:
        dh $@ --with autoreconf

override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- $(CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not able to use your example, though. I need to get the temp path were the binary file is placed, when the DEB package is about to be built. My code gives the path inside my system.  $${prefix} is not set for me, but it would be nice to find something like ${prefix} which equals to /temp/package/build/usr/ or something similar...

Comment: `\$${prefix}` is not set on my system either, it expands to the literal "`${prefix}`" which is set by `configure`. don't you use `configure` or is your configure script not based on `autoconf`?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to edit DESTDIR inside your project file.

Just use:

```
target.path = $$LIB_INSTALL_DIR

INSTALLS += target
```